# Need help Parsing strange JSON with scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am working on parsing json to spark dataframe in scala. I have a nested json file of 50 different records of different household items. On JSON I am trying to parse the equipment tag is as below:

```
"equipment":[{"tv":[""]}]
```

Due to this item name (ex: `tv` in this case) is becoming column name than values.

Ideally this tag should be like,

```
"equipment":["tv"]
```

Is there a way parse this type of JSON tags/ contents?

Due to this the dataframe schema is being shown as:

```
 |-- equipment: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- ac: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- tv: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Where you can see that (above) `ac` & `tv` are becoming column headers. Instead of that i need them to shown as values. The dataframe should look like:

```
+----------+
|equipment |
+----------+
|tv        |
|ac        |
+----------+
```

Comment: So is the question how to parse, or how to restructure the JSON before you parse it?

Comment: advise on either ways. If you can help me in parsing it that would be great. Ultimately I am looking to parsing it. Thanks.

Comment: It's already parsed. You clearly have the dataframe

Comment: sorry its not. I think i am not clear... if you see the schema i pasted, it says that ac & tv as column names than contents/ equipment types.

Comment: *the dataframe schema is being shown as*... Clear to me. The JSON must be parsed for you to *get a dataframe*, so what is the real question? How to iterate over the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `explode` function should have done the trick for you but looking at your `schema`, two `explode` functions would do the trick as

```
val newdf = dataframe.withColumn("equipment", explode($"equipment"))
newdf.withColumn("equipment", explode(array($"equipment.*"))).show(false)
```

With these steps you should have the desired result as in the question.

**Edited**

From your comments it seems that you are trying to explode the fieldNames not the values. So the following code should work then

```
val newdf = dataframe.withColumn("equipment", explode($"equipment"))
sc.parallelize(newdf.select("equipment.*").schema.fieldNames.toSeq).toDF("equipment").show(false)
```

Here's the complete code I am testing with

```
val data = Seq("""{"equipment":[{"tv":[""],"ac":[""]}]}""")
val dataframe = sqlContext.read.json(sc.parallelize(data))
dataframe.printSchema()
val newdf = dataframe.withColumn("equipment", explode($"equipment"))
sc.parallelize(newdf.select("equipment.*").schema.fieldNames.toSeq).toDF("equipment").show(false)
```

the printed schema matches with yours

```
root
 |-- equipment: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- ac: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- tv: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

And the result I get matches with your expected result

```
+---------+
|equipment|
+---------+
|ac       |
|tv       |
+---------+
```

Comment: I guess your solution works when `ac` & `tv` are values of the `equipment` array but they are not. Here `ac` & `tv` are becoming column headers due to structure of JSON. I want that to be restructured to make them values.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But I am getting `equipment` itself as values not the items (ex: `ac` & `tv`).

Comment: May be I need to try like this `sc.parallelize(test8.select($"equipment.ac").schema.fieldNames.toSeq).toDF("equipment").show(false)` but it is not feasible as it will not be generic.

Comment: I have updated my question . Try that and lets discuss to get to the solution your require. :)

Comment: @ Ramesh, I haven't tried this yet, will let you know the outcome.